# how to open up a dialog in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, dialog

I am using codeigniter for my project.I am not so familiar with ajax. I have a list of users in table format.For each row there is a button to view the detail of each user. On click of the button, I want a dialog showing all the details of user in tabular format. Can anybody show me with code how it can be done? My code is like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-rounded btn-sm product_detail"   id="<?=$record->serviceId;?>"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Product" >
        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="header-modal" aria-hidden="true"></div>

    <script>    
            $('body').delegate('.product_detail', 'click', function() {
               var serviceId = $(this).attr('serviceId');
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?= base_url();?>service/popup",
                data: {serviceId: serviceId},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                                $("#header-modal").html("<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>"+
                                                "<div class='modal-content'>" +
                                                        "<div class='modal-header'>" +
                                                                "<button type='' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'><i class='icons-office-52'>Close</i></button>" +
                                                                "<h4 class='modal-title'><strong>Product Detail</strong></h4>" +
                                                        "</div>" +
                                                        "<div class='modal-body' id='modal_body'>" +

                                                        "</div>" +
                                                        "<div class='modal-footer'> " +
                                                             "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger  btn-embossed bnt-square' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancle</button>" +
                                                        "</div>" +
                                                "</div>"+
                                        "</div>"
                                    );
                                    $('#header-modal').modal('show');
                }
            });

            });
    </script>
```

controller code:

```
    public function popup()
        {
            $serviceId = $this->input->post('serviceId');
            $data['serviceInfo'] = $this->product->getServiceById($serviceId);

            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

I have also included js and css files also in my view.

Comment: first show us your $data in var_dump(); before json_encode(), second in modal you just need to print data or you want some HTML design with it too, third are you facing any error during this process? Forth Is this script tag is in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this to open modal on button click and onclick function to get all the details of the user you want to show in the modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded btn-sm product_detail" data-target="#editPermission" data-toggle="modal" onclick="yourfunction('pass id here')">
        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
</button>
```

data-target is for your modal id, in onclick call your function.

Answer (score 0):

Html Section is

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Product Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Product Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Product Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="prod_id">1</td>
                <td class="prod_name">Apple</td>
                <td class="prod_desc">Frout</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="viewBtn">View</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="prod_id">2</td>
                <td class="prod_name">Orange</td>
                <td class="prod_desc">Frout</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="viewBtn">View</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="modal fade" id="header-modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'><i class='icons-office-52'>Close</i></button>
                    <h4 class='modal-title'><strong>Product Detail</strong></h4>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body' id='modal_body'>
                    Product Id : <span class="modal_prod_id"></span><br/>
                    Product Name : <span class="modal_prod_name"></span><br/>
                    Product Desc : <span class="modal_prod_desc"></span><br/>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger  btn-embossed bnt-square' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancle</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script section is

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.viewBtn').click(function(event) {
                /* Act on the event */
                var cur = $(this);
                var id = cur.closest('.prod_id').text();
                var name = cur.closest('.prod_name').text();
                var desc = cur.closest('.prod_desc').text();
                $('.modal_prod_id').text(id);
                $('.modal_prod_name').text(name);
                $('.modal_prod_desc').text(desc);
                $('#header-modal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
```